# How to hide precious HTML from user eyes?

Tags: html, firebug

I am thinking to create an website that generates HTML through a wizard.
Finally, I want to make the users to buy the generated HTML source if they like what they see.

But I don't want to let the users to steal the HTML, CSS and JS that I use to create the effect they want.

I want a technique which is immune to Firebug and Right Click -> View Page Source.

Any thoughts ?

edit: I remember something about iframes or frameset, but I'm not sure how to fool the browser and Firebug to execute the code without updating their capability of showing that source code. A popup is also a possible solution.

edit 2: html hosted in silverlight ? will you use it ?

Comment: Many duplicate questions. The answer is: it's _impossible_ to prevent someone (who has trivial technical know-how) from stealing anything that is received by their computer: movies, music, websites, documents - anything! Your only option is to limit what you send in the unpaid version, and hope that your users find that useful enough to make them want to buy.

Comment: See [how to protect client side codes...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512849/how-to-protect-client-side-codes)

Comment: Take a screenshot? If you provide a live page, there's nothing you can do.

Comment: "immune to ... View Page Source"  Funny.  Very funny.  Funniest question all day.

Comment: @S.Lott I mean... they see a blank page or see code that they can't understand

Comment: If there's a will, there's a way.  (This goes both ways.)

Comment: @pixel3cs: You are basically out of luck. The way the web works is that the server will serve up the html, css, and javascript to the user upon request. It's not that I think your idea is *wrong*, but it is contrary to the design and architecture of the web, so you probably won't be able to make it work very well at all. The real magic - IMO - should be server side, always.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best thing you can do is to just obfuscate your code. Trying to hide the source is not going to work (for ex: if you disable right click-> view source that doesn't stop them from using the menu or saving the page or using a shortcut key or writing an app to stream the http request into a file and open that, etc).

Firstly, depending on what you are doing you can have the HTML code loaded through JS after the page load (AJAX).

As far as your JS goes:
[Free Obfuscator](http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/)
[Not Free Obfuscator](http://www.stunnix.com/prod/jo/)

In the end though, there is no stopping someone who really wants to get that source. Even obfuscated code can be rebuilt (though it's hell on wheels painful depending on how good the obfuscator is).

Comment: thanks, this seems to be the best solution for me. I already load my final code via AJAX, so, it will be simple to add another layer that obfuscate it.

Comment: "you can have the HTML code loaded through JS after the page load"  This does essentially nothing.  It is still trivial to use a tool like Firebug to dump the parsed DOM as HTML.

Comment: I've never used Firebug to know it can do that. I guess the point I was driving at was that you can't hide your code, but you can distort it and layer it enough to make it a pain in the butt to reverse-engineer it though (not impossible, just a pain).

Answer (score 0):

To really protect the sample HTML from prying eyes, you'd need to render it on the server-side and only pass image data to the client. If you want the user to be able to interact with the sample as if it were a normal Web page, you'll also need to send their pointer and keyboard inputs to the server and update the displayed image when necessary. At that point, though, you're basically making an HTTP-based version of VNC. This is definitely possible, but I don't think it will be easy, and I doubt there are any existing software packages to let you do this. If I were you, I'd rethink my business model a bit.

Comment: your solution works, and indeed, is the best if we think at it. but is too much for something that should be simple.

Comment: Oh, definitely. I don't expect you (or anyone else) to actually implement something so complicated. The cost of implementation would almost certainly outweigh an additional security it would provide.

Comment: Why should it be simple? The web does not work this way, by design. There's not going to be any simple way to get around that.

Answer (score 0):

Sending XSL-templated XML to the browser may be enough fool some, and it will work more or less the same in many modern browsers including IE6 (maybe even 5.5).

But really, trying to hide the HTML code isn't going to work if anyone halfway serious wants to get it.

Answer (score 0):

> I am thinking to create an website that generates HTML through a wizard.
>   Finally, I want to make the users to buy the generated HTML source if they like what they see.

If this is what you need you might consider the possibility of creating a *preview* of the page as an image, and provide the download of the source only after the user agreed and paid. There is no magic way to let a browser display a code that you can't see.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a video, showing the functionality and upload the same, which may help users to view / feel it.